# Can't configure Jenkins and Git

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I'm obviously missing something simple: I can't figure out how to make Jenkins build a project on GitHub:

- I created a build user and added them to the project.
- I generated an SSH key on the build machine as the Jenkins user, and added that to the GitHub build account
- I created a new GitHub project and pasted the ssh URI as it appears on the widget on the GitHub page.

Jenkins tries to authenticate and fails.

I tried with credentials set to "none" as well as global credentials matching the GitHub account.  Nothing seems to work.

This should be easy.  I'm stumped on this for hours, and am quite frustrated at this point.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you access Github as the Jenkins user from the command-line?

Comment: "I created a new GitHub project" -> "I created a new Jenkins project"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, seriously?  I created the key with passphrase.  Once I recreated without one, all was well.  But I thought that the credentials I entered would have provided the passphrase...apparently not.

Silly oversight, annoyed it took me so long to notice the problem!